# Java Sound using specific Ports and DataLines

Tags: java, javasound

This feels like the 100th Java Sound related question I've asked on this site but I cant find the answer any where in the Java Sound API or at jsresources.org. I'm making a multitrack recorder and so far its working great, well better than expected, what I'm having problems with currently is allowing a user to select an input for each track at runtime. Right now my program just takes an available `TargetDataLine` from the `Mixer` and I'm able to control the volume during recording as well as the balance. If I list the `Ports` and allow a user to select a specific `Port`, for example the internal microphone in laptop, how do I get a `TargetDataLine` for that specific `Port` to use for recording? Is it a matter of closing all unused `Ports`?

I also just noticed when listing the `Ports` source refers to input and target output, I just got used to `DataLines` being the other way around if someone could clarify that I'd appreciate it.

And something that may help me solve my current problem is understanding the relationship between `Ports` and `DataLines`, I know what the two are but I don't understand why you cant get a `DataLine` from a `Port` just like you would a mixer, so what is the relationship between the two?

Comment: I count 3 questions there..

Comment: It started with one and a half then while listing the ports I noticed the ports were seemingly backward and realized what I may actually be asking is how the two interact with each other. I'm not asking for three specific answers, any advice at all is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting ahead of what I have tried to do, but perhaps I can still help a bit!

Did you see this summary of the differences between a Port and a DataLine?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/package-summary.html

It seems to me a given Port will work with only ONE of either a SourceDataLine or a TargetDataLine depending upon whether it is an input or output port.

Did you also try the examples from here?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html

It seems to me that since a Port extends Line, the example code for reading audio should work if you substitute your Port for their Line (assuming it is an input Port). Does the example code work for you?

I'm guessing that if you are mixing sound from more than one Port, it would require unpacking the sound data, doing your own addition of the sound values and repacking them as PCM samples (i.e., doing your own audio mixing) for a single output line.

Comment: To be honest I may be getting ahead of myself. I have been through the documentation including the sampled package summary. I understand a Port is either an input or output therefore the DataLine would have to match. My question is how do you get a DataLine from a specific Port? I've tried all kinds of examples and even fixed the source code to compile Jam Session from jsresources.org, still no luck. Port does extend Line but in the example they're using a DataLine which also inherits from Line but Ports and DataLines aren't interchangeable, for example you cant write/read to/from a Port.

Comment: Sorry I ran out of space. As far as mixing goes, you're referring to a type of mix down which is useful for saving multiple tracks as an mp3 or wav or whatever. But the data is recorded to separate tracks and played back simultaneously, there is an example at jsresources.org called Audio Concat, take a look at that for an example of mixing down audio files. What I'm trying to do is get a TargetDataLine that reads from a specific, user selected Port and a SourceDataLine that writes to a different specific user selected Port. Thanks for your answer, I appreciate your input.

Comment: If you're working with sound in Java you may find this useful, I'm a little bit closer to figuring it out. Mixers seem to come in pairs. A DataLine mixer and a Port mixer. So you'll have at least one Mixer for SourceDataLines, Clips and TargetDataLines and at least one Mixer for Ports for each hardware device and I've been identifying them by what I think is the location (for example hw:0, hw:1, etc.). So first I identify the hardware device I want to use, and get the location of it then I create DataLine.Info and Port.Info objects and use the isLineSupported(Line.Info) method.

Comment: If you want the Port Mixer pass in the Port.Info object and for the DataLine mixer use the DataLine.Info object in the parameter to find the appropriate Mixer. Now what I need to do is figure out how to basically line up the DataLine from its Mixer with a Port from the port Mixer. It really might just be a matter of making sure the unused Ports on the port Mixer are closed but that seems like it may conflict with other software on the users machine so I'm hoping there is a DataLine specific to each Port and I am able to match them so it doesn't matter what is open and in use by other software.